# How do I prevent reminder popups for meetings I'm not attending?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2016

When someone sends me an invitation for an event that happened in the past, Outlook will instantly pop up a reminder on my desktop, even though I haven't even opened the mail about the event yet.

[image: Outlook event reminder]

How can I prevent Outlook from opening these reminders for events I'm not attending?

Comment: So this notification happens even if you don't accept it the invitation?

Comment: @Ramhound Correct. It instantly appears as soon as the email lands in my inbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can turn this off, in File -> Options -> Mail -> Tracking, uncheck the

> Automatically process meeting requests and responses to meeting requests and polls

This feature is designed for a reason though, it is so people can see you have tentative appointments to reduce/prevent double bookings.

I do not know how you can achieve this based upon the time of the event (although you don't explicitly ask for it, although I suspect it would be helpful), my best guess is VBa

There is a caveat I just read

> Even though a meeting request will no longer be automatically added as Tentative to your Calendar upon receiving, it will still be added as Tentative as soon as you select the meeting request in your message list.

[Details for quote](http://www.msoutlook.info/question/do-not-automatically-accept-meeting-as-tentative)

Comment: That option is already checked.

Comment: Sorry @oliversalzburg I meant uncheck

Comment: Perfect. Works exactly as I would want it to work, *especially* with the mentioned caveat.

Comment: This seems likely to remove all reminders? What about the crazy concept of receiving reminders for upcoming events and not events that have passed???

Comment: I think that is a new question @ZachSmith :)